# PHP Execute Function parameters from list

Tags: php

I have a function which requires 2 parameters.

```
myFunction($para1,$para2) ...
```

To use the function I just do this:

```
myFunction('para 1','para 2');
```

My question is ... how can I loop this function so I can have it read the parameters from a list?

For example if I have a list of names and surnames...

```
name1, surname1
name2, surname2
etc
loop here
myFunction('name1','surname1');
next is
myFunction('name2','surname2');

and so on...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is the number of occurrences of parameter one equals that of parameter 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you have that list of parameters?

If you have it in an associative array you could do something like this:

```
foreach($list as $key => $value){
myFunction($key,$value);
}
```

Comment: How can you be certain that both the parameters have a key, value association!?